# mysqli_fetch_assoc ONLY returns the second element of array even with iteration

Tags: php, mysqli

This is my code:

```
$query2 = "select * from teaches where teacherid_fk LIKE '$teacherid_fk'";
$userinfo2 = mysqli_query($conn, $query2);
while ($line = mysqli_fetch_assoc($userinfo2)) {echo json_encode($line);}
```

Somehow, the result I'm getting is only one array when there should be two arrays displayed. I need both arrays to be displayed, but my code only displays the second array.
This is the db:
[dbTableofTeaches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y81jE.png)

Am I doing something wrong here? Just recently learned PHP and any help is deeply appreciated. :)

**EDIT 2:** If I do the code like this:

```
$query2 = "select * from teaches where teacherid_fk LIKE '$teacherid_fk'";
$userinfo2 = mysqli_query($conn, $query2);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($userinfo2);
echo json_encode($row);
```

The result is this: {"teaches_id":"2","teacherid_fk":"1","subjectid_fk":"65","quarterid_fk":"1","gradeid_fk":"5","sectionid_fk":"13","schoolyearid_fk":"2"} [**which is actually the first array I was looking for!**]

**EDIT 3:** Okay I'm getting more confused. I've tried to edit the db so it now looks like this: [dbTableOfTeaches2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UWYG.png). With the same (first) code above, I refreshed the page, and the second and third arrays are now displayed, **but still no sign of the first array!** The only way I was able to display the first array was use the second code above.

Comment: How are you reading the response? There should be two JSON strings `echo`d. You also appear to be open to SQL injections, parameterize your query. I also would use `=`, not `like`, when looking for an exact match.

Comment: chris85 thanks for the suggestions. As for your question, all I can see on my page is this: {"teaches_id":"2","teacherid_fk":"1","subjectid_fk":"55","quarterid_fk":"1","gradeid_fk":"5","sectionid_fk":"13","schoolyearid_fk":"2"}

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
$query2 = "select * from teaches where teacherid_fk = '$teacherid_fk'";
$userinfo2 = mysqli_query( $conn, $query2 );

$respons = array();

while ( $line = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $userinfo2 ) ) {

    $respons[] = $line;

}

echo json_encode($respons);
```

Comment: Still displays the second array. No sign of the first array. [I'm beginning to feel like PHP hates me. Hahah just kidding.]

Comment: I checked it in the phpmyadmin and it really fetched two rows. Please see the corrected "new" (EDIT 2) code up above -- I corrected it recently.